# Is it possible to play in 415 hertz in GarageBand?

Tags: garageband

Does GarageBand have the option to play in 415 hertz ? The default is of course 440 hertz (concert tuning), but can you change that? And how ?

Comment: OS X or iOS garage band? Please edit the post and tag please.